# trailing dot in local part of email

Tags: regex, email, email-address

In our online shop, we ran into a problem wherein a certain user can't purchase because of an "invalid email address". It looks like this:

`her.email.address.@docomo.ne.jp`

I think what's setting off the invalid email error is the trailing dot in the local part of the email. In the code, I commented out the second condition:

`if (isc_substr($local, 0, 1) == '.' || isc_substr($local, -1, 1) == '.')`

to make it work. Is this safe? Or should we advise the customer to change her email address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: My old answer was wrong.

I see absolutely no safety implications in this rule, but [RfC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) explicitly only allows dots inside the local part of the mail address, not at the beginning and end. That being said, I would not be surprised if *in practice,* it would still just work with a lot of mail servers. So, while `.@example.com` is not a valid address according to [RfC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322), for practical purposes, it could be a working address, only the mail server for `example.com` can know.

As I said, the relevant spec is [RfC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322), taking into account that [RfC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) adds the restriction that the local part not have more than 64 characters. And, yes, the standard allows for a lot of addresses that will simply not work for very many web sites or mail programs, such as `"this is v@lid!"@example.com`. It is unwise to use this kind of addresses, but that is because of software bugs that lead to them not being accepted.

Comment: It's actually the Interspire Shopping Cart, we bought this software. There is no comment explaining why having a dot at the start and end of the local part of email is invalid. Isn't there like a spec or a standard we can check to see whether this is really valid or not?

Comment: Yes, RFC 5322 allows strange quoted email addresses, but it does **not** allow a local part to start or end with a dot in an unquoted local part.

Comment: Oh, true. I had not realized that restriction. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 12):

That email address is indeed violating the standard (RFC 5322), and I would advice the user to change her address. However, there *should* not be any security implications when you allow your local parts to end in dots.

The standard also doesn't allow two or more consecutive dots, and this restriction can be a bit more security relevant: Think of something like `../../`. Yes, slashes are allowed in email addresses, and code that isn't prepared for that *might* do something nasty with the local part. Chances are low, but, you know, I've *seen* things… ;)

Since the standard is a bit hard to read, here's what it says:

RFC 5322 allows having dots in the local part, however, there are two important limitations: It does not allow two or more consecutive dots, and it also does **not** allow the local part to start or end with a dot.

[Section 3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) describes the `local-part`, and the three syntaxes it may have. The "usual" one is the `dot-atom` syntax, and that is essentially defined in [section 3.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.3) as

```
dot-atom-text   =   1*atext *("." 1*atext)
```

where `atext` are printable US-ASCII characters with some exceptions:

```
atext           =   ALPHA / DIGIT /    ; Printable US-ASCII
                    "!" / "#" /        ;  characters not including
                    "$" / "%" /        ;  specials.  Used for atoms.
                    "&" / "'" /
                    "*" / "+" /
                    "-" / "/" /
                    "=" / "?" /
                    "^" / "_" /
                    "`" / "{" /
                    "|" / "}" /
                    "~"
```

So `dot-atom-text` is basically defined as "at least one `atext` character, followed by zero or more occurences of [a dot followed by one or more `atext` characters]". That means `abc` is okay and `a.bc.d` as well, but `.abc` is not (because it doesn't start with `atext`), and neither are `a..b` (because there's no `atext` following the first dot) or `abc.` (again because there's no `atext` following).

As I said above, you can choose to ignore those restrictions (although I would advise against allowing consecutive dots), but essentially your shopping cart software is perfectly right to disallow that email address.